# jQuery & font-awesome - click() happens twice if mouse is not moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have two font-awesome icons wired up with a $.click() listener that should hide the icon clicked and shows the opposite icon in its place.  See https://jsfiddle.net/sz7Ldynr/3/.

If you click the icon more than once without moving the mouse, then the .click function fires for both icons but only some of the time.  On Chrome and Edge, it is about 9 out of 10 clicks, on FF it is only about 1 out of every 5 clicks. If you move the mouse in-between clicks, then it works normally.

HTML:

```
<div class="collapsible">
  <i class="toggle-content fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></i>
  <i class="toggle-content fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="content">
     <h3>Hello</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( '.collapsible .toggle-content' ).click( function() { 
  $( this ).parent().find( '.content' ).toggle();
  $( this ).parent().find( '.toggle-content' ).toggle();
} );
```

Is there any way to avoid registering a click with both listeners if the user does not move the mouse?

Comment: Are you sure your mouse works fine?

Comment: I agree with Arthur. I've been trying to repro this issue for a few minutes (Chrome, FF, Edge) and I'm unable to see it happen.

Comment: You can try [**this solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/sz7Ldynr/5/) (a bit cleaner), but overall, your code is fine.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a mouse problem.  If i tap the touch pad or use an external mouse it works fine.  Thanks for highlighting toggleClass Artur